# get database field value using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

Is there any other way I could access the database using javascript? I have progress bars and  I need to check whether the value of a field in my database is true to keep them moving. I've already google-d about it and I found out that it's not possible. If I use cookies, then I have to redefine the cookie everytime I change the computer where I log in. 
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [get data from mysql database to use in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568965/get-data-from-mysql-database-to-use-in-javascript)

Comment: i saw that post, i thought it was different, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to call a php (or asp or coldfusion) script which will return the value of the database field