# PhoneGap for Android - Connect to Database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, cordova

I have been trawling the internet for days now but nothing I can find seems to be a viable solution to my problem.

I am trying to create an Android Application using **PhoneGap** for Android (HTML5, CSS3 & JavaScript). I need the application to connect to a database. So far, all I have found is posts on *how to connect to the embedded WebSQL database* which is now deprecated. I already have a MySQL database set up that I want to connect with.

Can any of you lovely people point me in the direction of any posts that will help me out, or can any of you help me out directly with the issue i'm facing? I'm new to PhoneGap and Android Development.

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568965/get-data-from-mysql-database-to-use-in-javascript