# Extract data from mysql and use them in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to extract/get data from MySQL databse and use them in javascript. I found [get data from mysql database to use in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568965/get-data-from-mysql-database-to-use-in-javascript) very useful but I'm not able to show anything (I've never used jQuery, so probably I'm missing something but I'm not able to figure out what yet)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';
require 'function/security.php';

$records = array();

if($result = $db->query("SELECT geoLat,geoLong FROM Stop")){
    if($result->num_rows){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        //$result->free();
    }
}

/*echo '<pre>', print_r($result),'</pre>';
echo '<pre>', print_r($records),'</pre>';*/
echo json_encode($records);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BrindisiBus</title>
    <style>
    /* style settings for Google map */
    #map-canvas{
        width : 500px;  /* map width */
        height: 500px;  /* map height */
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--- API GOOGLE MAPS V3 -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
    $.getJSON('paline.php', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(fieldName, fieldValue) {
        $("#" + fieldName).val(fieldValue);
      });
    });
    /*
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
*/
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map-canvas' ></div><br/>
    <p id="total"></p>
    <p id="fieldName"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

With the query I get longitude and latitude, than I should save that values in js and create markers on the map.
Is it possible to do everything in the same file?
How could I check if getJSON is working at least and if it's giving errors?

Comment: Do you have elements having ids geoLat and geoLong in HTML?

Comment: geoLat and geoLong are field of a table of the database

Comment: $("#" + fieldName).val(fieldValue); here fieldName must exists in HTML

Comment: Do you mean <p id="fieldName"></p> ? I tried also with <input type="text" id="fieldName" /> but I don't get result

Comment: I mean <p id="geoLat"></p> and <p id="geoLong"></p> try with this

Comment: No, that doesn't work, I miss something else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79415/discussion-between-alessiomtx-and-vishal-shah).

Comment: this will work for you if you follow some method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require 'db/connect.php';
    require 'function/security.php';

    $records = array();

    if($result = $db->query("SELECT geoLat,geoLong FROM Stop")){
        if($result->num_rows){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $records[] = $row;
            }
            //$result->free();
        }
    }

    /*echo '<pre>', print_r($result),'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($records),'</pre>';*/
    $data=json_encode($records);

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>BrindisiBus</title>
        <style>
        /* style settings for Google map */
        #map-canvas{
            width : 500px;  /* map width */
            height: 500px;  /* map height */
        }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--- API GOOGLE MAPS V3 -->
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
var data=<?php echo $data; ?>
    function initialize() {

          $.each(data, function(fieldName, fieldValue) {
            $("#fieldName").val(fieldValue.geoLat);
          });

        /*
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    */
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map-canvas' ></div><br/>
        <p id="total"></p>
        <p id="fieldName"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Nothing is show in fieldName, but now var data in javascript contain the object

Comment: come on chat i will explain you